# Font Icons Not Showing Up

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, css, magento

Hello I am working with Magento Version 1.9.0.1 I have been racking my head over and over and I can not get this to work. Any subdomain to my primary domain is not rendering the font-icons that came with the theme, the primary domain however is showing these icons. On another note Safari is rendering my font-icons from my subdomain but Chrome and FireFox are not. Here is what the Chrome Dev Console is outputting

`Font from origin 'http://brandster.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://breezesta.brandster.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

I did add this to the .htaccess file of the subdomain

`<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>`

and it is still not working. Can anyone please shed some light on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if your htaccess is blocking the use of files from other domains including sub-domains. Maybe try and see if this works?

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*.brandster.com"
 </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

So if that works for you.